# Fill background Color to div dynamically

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have some div blocks and I want to fill background color only to few div blocks dynamically say only to the first 5, how to do that in react dynamically, here is my code

```
const ImageBlock = ({block}) => {
  const number = 5
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {block.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{
                borderStyle: 'solid',
                borderWidth: '2px',
                backgroundColor: number ? "#000" : null,
              }}
            >
              {item}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: try `backgroundColor: index < 5 ? "#000" : null,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you want is `index < number` so replace `backgroundColor: number ? "#000" : null,` with `backgroundColor: index < number ? "#000" : null,`.